# How to create a vector of dates

Tags: julia

I would like to be able to create a vector of dates given a start and and end date in a dataframe. However, I receive the following error: "Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Day"

```
using DataFrames, Tidier, TidierDates

df = DataFrame(date_start = "2019-01-01", date_end = "2019-01-31")
describe(df)
df[!, :date_start] = TidierDates.ymd.(df[!, :date_start])
df[!, :date_end] = TidierDates.ymd.(df[!, :date_end])
describe(df)

df[1,:date_start]:df[1,:date_end]
```

I thought something like this might work, but no:

```
date_vec = Dates.value(df[1,:date_start]):1:Dates.value(df[1,:date_end]) |> collect
date_days = Dates.Day(date_vec)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hUBiydGl6E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on an extended DataFrame to show the row-wise operation.

```
using DataFrames
using Dates

res = collect.(range.(Date.(df.date_start), Date.(df.date_end)));

res[1]
31-element Vector{Date}:
 2019-01-01
 2019-01-02
...
 2019-01-30
 2019-01-31

res[2]
9-element Vector{Date}:
 2019-01-03
 2019-01-04
...
 2019-01-10
 2019-01-11
```

##### extended Data

```
df = DataFrame(["2019-01-01" "2019-01-31"; 
                "2019-01-03" "2019-01-11"], ["date_start", "date_end"])

2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ date_start  date_end
     │ String      String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 2019-01-01  2019-01-31
   2 │ 2019-01-03  2019-01-11
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but there may be better solutions:

```
df[1,:date_start]:Dates.Day(1):df[1,:date_end] |> collect
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Dates` package in Julia `Base` is very good. I think `TidierDates` makes things more complicated to be honest. No need to create a string (`"2019-01-01"`) first and then convert it into a date. You can just use the `Date` function like so: `Date(2019,01,01)`.

Keeping that in mind, you only need to know how range objects are created, which is `start:step:end`. You want to start with a `Date` and then step by a duration `Day` until you reach another `Date`.

Summed up:

```
using Dates

Date(2019,01,01):Day(1):Date(2019,01,31)
```